# How to update data in hive?

Tags: hadoop

I have used this query to update data

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE record PARTITION(dated='03-08-2013')                    
     SELECT id, f_name, marks, CASE WHEN id=224 THEN 'KUMAR' ELSE l_name END AS l_name
     FROM record;
```

but creates some problem column miss managed l_name appeared in marks column.
any help

Answer (score 0):

Use your query like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE record PARTITION(dated='03-08-2013') 
SELECT id, f_name, marks, CASE WHEN id=224 THEN 'KUMAR' ELSE l_name END AS l_name
FROM record WHERE [_whereClause_];
```

Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200871/update-set-option-in-hive) for more clarification:

Comment: and there is no need to use Where Clause its just optional part u can use it or not.

Comment: Great, Please share your answer and resolution also. It will help others in future.

Comment: Hello please make sure which column you want to update as I update l_name then write previous column after SELECT and rest of column after END AS like l_name,marks here is this code-              INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE record PARTITION(dated='03-08-2013') 
SELECT id, f_name, CASE WHEN id=224 THEN 'KUMAR' ELSE l_name END AS l_name,marks
FROM record;                                                             hope this will help thanks Regard:- Ashwani Sharma