# HDInsight Azure Blob Storage Data Update

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight, hadoop-partitioning, azure-blob-storage

I am considering HDInsight with Hive and data loaded on Azure Blob Storage.
There is a combination of both historic and changing data.
Does the solution mentioned in [Update , SET option in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200871/update-set-option-in-hive) work with blob storage too?
The below Hive statement change the data in blob storage which is my requirement too?

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE _tableName_ PARTITION ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT OVERWRITE will write new file(s) into the cluster file system. In HDInsight the file system is backed by Azure blobs, the `wasb://...` and `wasb:///...` names. Everything Hive does to the cluster file system, like overwriting them, will accordingly be reflected in the Azure storage BLOBs. See [Use Hive with HDInsight](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-hive/) for more details.