# Update a value in Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have gone through some of the Stackoveflow question . but I was not able to do the same.

Hive doesnot support update but a workaround for that is to create partition to table.

How to update a record in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

The update feature in Hive is planned in the next release.

As a workaround , You could try the below :

1. Add a flag column default as I and a timestamp column
2. consider partitions as your primary key fields (combination).
3. whenever a new record (updated ) on this primary key combination set the flag as U.
4. Write a custom serde class where in only U records are shown.

NOTE : There will be duplicated data , but serde should only show the latest U data corresponding to the latest timestamp in the timestamp column.

Comment: Are we able to do with partitions?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200871/update-set-option-in-hive

Comment: i havent work using partitions . Reading the post i guess it might work.