# Update column in HIVE

Tags: hive

I have a table in php which is in this format:

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS {$tableName} (fileContent VARCHAR(250), description VARCHAR(250), dimension DOUBLE, fileName VARCHAR(250)) ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/var/www/ASOIS_Proiect/metadata/'

I want for a situation to update only description field if fileName='a' and 'size'='12' already exist in database.

Any idea please? I tried to update the file create for insert with command LOAD and flag OVERWRITE but it is not working.

Comment: As far as I know, Hive does not support update that way.

Comment: Hey, Yes but i think that it might be a way to update some columns..

Comment: Seems Hive 0.14 added update statement on tables that support ACID.https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update

Comment: Follow this [link][1] it may help you! 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200871/update-set-option-in-hive