# count function doesn't work in hiveql

Tags: hiveql

hello friends i have written a hive query to get the count number as a variable. I will use this variable to update a column. But this query doesn't function well. It always give a Syntax error: ")" unexpected. Can anybody help me regarding this error? Here is my query-
select count(tank_items_id) AS count_tank_items 
from master_data_assortment.tank_items_actual 
where item_type = 'shop_offer';
Thank you.
Regards
Mirish

Comment: this query is correct ->  "select count(tank_items_id) AS count_tank_items from master_data_assortment.tank_items_actual where item_type = 'shop_offer';" are you sure you are getting Syntax error for this query

Comment: @Nirmal, first of all thanks for reply. yes I have tried the same query and getting this error. I have searched everywhere and I found no solution. i really don't understand whats wrong with this query.

Comment: can you post the full error

Comment: $ select count(tank_items_id) AS count_tank_items from master_data_assortment.tank_items_actual where item_type = 'shop_offer';
sh: 7: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running as `hive -e "select count(tank_items_id) AS count_tank_items from master_data_assortment.tank_items_actual where item_type = 'shop_offer';"`

you should run in hive prompt not in cli

Comment: yes i got my error. I was not in hive environment. I got an intiger value Now the query works fine. But my next step is to use this value to update column. So I have written a query-update meta_statistics.tank_items
set shop_offers_actual_before =
select count(tank_items_id) as count_tank_items
from master_data_assortment.tank_items_actual where item_type = 'shop_offer'
where t_stamp = '2016-11-21 14:57:13'; It gives ths error: FAILED: ParseException line 3:1 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'count' '(' in expression specification

Comment: i think you can't update like that. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200871/update-set-option-in-hive

Comment: Thanks Nirmal, I will go through it.